# Is it possible to consolidate framework dependencies with XCode?

Tags: xcode, frameworks

For example, if I created a framework that put together Ogre3D with RakNet and OIS, and I only wanted to have to distribute my framework for recompilation, is that possible?

I tried doing something like that, but I was getting linker errors. That would seem to suggest that you can't do that (and that's fine), but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible as long as the person doing the compiling has all those other frameworks. I'm not sure what you would want Xcode to do for you.

Comment: Well, I was trying to simplify some things by not having to ask people to get those other frameworks.